# Deployment validation locks

Tags: deployment, change-set

From [Change Set Development Model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/declarative-change-set-development/test-in-the-integration-environment-and-deploy-changes) on trailhead it talks about how metadata is locked when attempting a deployment.

> Validation locks the resources being deployed. You can still read and write data to the org, but you can’t make any setup changes that modify the metadata. Making changes to locked resources or items related to those resources can cause errors. Start a validation when things aren’t too busy, like during off-peak usage hours. Limit changes to your org until the validation process completes.

I can't seem to find official documentation on this and I would like to learn more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read this [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334937&type=1&mode=1), which has a bunch of useful links to other articles as well. I'm not sure there's an *actual* official documentation on this, but to summarize, making a change requires a lock. Deployments will take this lock until they complete, including validations. This prevents race conditions from being possible (e.g. you delete a field while the system is validating a trigger that uses that field). All you need to know is that you can't make multiple, concurrent changes to the org at once to prevent "weird things" from happening. As far as I'm aware, there are two main locks. The first is for Sharing, which is when you add, change, or recalculate a sharing rule, or modify a public group or a role in the role hierarchy. The second lock is for other admin changes, such as deploying code, adding fields, etc. Usually, these locks are very short, except for validations and deployments, as all unit tests may need to run.

Comment: These locks only happen on the org you are deploying to? There wouldn't be a lock on both orgs if you are deploying a change set, would there?

Comment: @TylerZika Correct. Deployments only affect the org being deployed to.